# How to autochange the name attribute of button in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Hello StackOverFlowers,

I have created a table in my JSP page and the code is like this:
........

```
<% while(resultSet.next()){ %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=resultSet.getString("SN")%></td>
            <td><%= resultSet.getString("fname")%></td>
            <td><%= resultSet.getString("mname")%></td>
            <td><%= resultSet.getString("lname")%></td>
            <td><%= resultSet.getString("gender")%></td>
            <td><%= resultSet.getString("email")%></td>
            <td><%= resultSet.getString("phone")%></td>
            <td><%= resultSet.getString("address")%></td>

            <td><img src="<c:url value="DBimage.jsp"/>" width="50" height="50"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name ="approve" value="Approve"/>


            </td>

        </tr>
        <% } %>
```

I want the name of the button to auto change. 
How can I do that? Is there any easy way?

Comment: Have you tried <input type="submit" name ="<%= buttonLabel %>" value="Approve"/> . You can choose to source this based on some value on the server side and creating a String variable by name buttonLabel in JSP

Comment: can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suraj , here you go. A quick prototype that shows the concept. The value of the button is created here in the JSP itself. If you want you can compute something on the server side , send that value through response and access it through the implicit parameter response or through session for example and assign this value. For the sake of simplicity i have just used a random.

I ran this on a local jetty instance and it works!. Hope it helps

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Random" %>

<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<%

Random random = new Random();
int randomInt = random.nextInt(42);
String submitName="Submit" + randomInt;

%>

<input type="submit" name ="<%= submitName %>" value="<%= submitName %>"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without using random, how can we do ?
If we use counter it's value will be reset.

Comment: I did it :)
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jstl` tag for it

```
 <input type="submit" name="approve" value="<c:out value="${param.Btnname}"/>" />
```

So you can change the value of your Button by assigning String value on your `btnName` variable

or in `JSP` Expression

```
 <input type="submit" name="approve" value='<%=request.getParameter("Btnname")%>' />
```

Comment: will this give me different names? or I have to do something manually?

Comment: well it depend on your code, if you try to change the value everytime user want to do something then you simply have to use setter for the btnName variable in you pojo or Servlet class